# multiple invocation of controller async method does not complete concurrently

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, async-await

I've the following *Home* controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task IndexAsync()
    {

        Response.Write($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - {DateTime.Now}  begin <br>");
        var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        await con.OpenAsync();
        Response.Write($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - {DateTime.Now}  connection opened <br>");
        var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Await";
        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        Response.Write($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} - {DateTime.Now}  end <br>");
    }
```

i invoke same method concurrently in two different tabs in browser and get the following result:

**tab1**:

[image]

**tab2**:

[image]

sql procedure Await does only this:

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:5'
```

Session mode is OFF.
Why method does not complete parallel ?

Comment: Lots of parts here.  IIS, ASP, SQL. You could/should replace "two different tabs in browser" with a test script using HttpClient. And you don't have a real problem unless this holds up for multiple SELECT statements.

Comment: The connection is not being closed. Disposables should be disposed.

Comment: @bommelding  i've noticed , that browser process request sequentially, the question why ? session mode disabled